# How to check if the AMP module (Accelerated Mobile Pages) is working?

Tags: 7, mobile-tools, google-search-console

I'm testing the drupal AMP module (Accelerated Mobile Pages), well, I've installed it, pre-configured it (I've not created the subtheme..)but I've enabled it for one node (just for a test).

How can I test it ? Doing a google search on my browser ?

Thank you.

Comment: Be sure the header on the original page contains a reference to the AMP version of the page.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that needs to happen is to get it reindexed by Google so it knows about it.  I suggest configuring Google Search Console on your site https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/4559176?hl=en  You can request it to be reindexed there. It was called Google Webmaster Tools before they rebranded it.
Its as easy to set up as Google Analytics.  It shows a display of what your site looks like on desktop, as Google sees it.

It does show you want it looks like ton AMP.

Comment: @Sushi Why no upvote for this correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

To test AMP you can go to the node's URL (http://localhost:4000/your-page) and add '?amp' to force Drupal to display the AMP theme. (http://localhost:4000/your-page?amp).

If the amp theme doesn't load, you either haven't configured your AMP subtheme  properly in your repo or you haven't configured the AMP module properly within the Drupal admin panel.

If you want to check to make sure your AMP theme is AMP-valid you can install the Amp Validator Chrome Extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/amp-validator/nmoffdblmcmgeicmolmhobpoocbbmknc?hl=en). It will be green if the page is valid. If not, it will be red with the number of errors. Click on the extension's icon to read more about each error.